# Norton security toolbar is eating RAM

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

When ever i run chrome and use it for a while it starts getting slow. I checked the task manager and chrome was using about 1 Gig of ram. In chrome's task manager `Norton security toolbar` was the one using this huge amount.
I tried uninstalling/reinstalling Norton, but to no use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I saw it, the Norton Internet Toolbar is a separate package to Norton.

Go to Add/Remove Programs and take a look for the toolbar there.

If you can't find it, it is possible it is installed as an extension/addon.

- If it is a plugin, take a look here - chrome://plugins/ - you can disable (but not uninstall).
- If it is an extension, take a look here - chrome://extensions/ - you can disable and uninstall.

(Copy and paste those links to the omnibar).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have read that it helps against phishing and things like that so if i disable or uninstall it, will i be affected?

Comment: Norton software has got better in recent years, but, it is still awful. Chrome has built in phishing detection and various other protections. If you are nervous, I recommend you keep Norton, but, it will eat up your resources/there is nothing you can do there.